# prove existence of the limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

So I have the following problem:
$ x_0 = 1 , x_1 = 2 , $and $x_{n+1} = 2x_n + x_{n-1} $for $ n \geq 1.$

Show that: $\hspace{2mm} \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}   $ exists.

Then show that the Limit is equal to $\sqrt{2}-1$.

For this I thought i could use the fact that $x_n$ is bounded and I thought that it was monotonically falling, but that is not the case, so I ran out of ideas. And I don't know how to calculate the limit... Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Don´t forget to mark an answer as accepted!!! Have a look at your other questions as well. Then your "$\textrm{Thank you very much for your help!}$" is more credible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without guessing the limit you may proceed as follows:

- Set $q_n = \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$
  $$\Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 2x_n + x_{n-1} \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{q_n} = 2+q_{n-1}\Leftrightarrow q_n = \frac{1}{2+q_{n-1}}$$

Now, it follows
$$|q_{n+1} - q_n| = \left|\frac{1}{2+q_{n}} - \frac{1}{2+q_{n-1}} \right| = \left|\frac{q_{n-1} - q_n}{(\color{blue}{2}+q_{n})(\color{blue}{2}+q_{n-1})}\right|$$ $$< \frac{1}{\color{blue}{2\cdot 2}}\left|q_{n-1} - q_{n} \right| \stackrel{\mbox{see below}}{\Rightarrow} \boxed{(q_n) \mbox{ is convergent}}$$

So, we get for the limit
$$L =\frac{1}{2+L} \Leftrightarrow (L+1)^2=2 \stackrel{L>0}{\Rightarrow}\boxed{L = \sqrt{2}-1}$$

**Edit after comment:**

Additional info concerning the convergence of the sequence:

- $q_{n+1} = q_1 + \sum_{k=1}^n(q_{k+1} -q_k)$
- The sums converge (absolutely) as $|q_{k+1} -q_k| < \left( \frac{1}{4}\right)^{k-1}|q_2 - q_1|$ since
- $\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(q_{k+1} -q_k) \right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|q_{k+1} -q_k| < |q_2 - q_1|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{4}\right)^{k-1} < \infty$
- As $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n(q_{k+1} -q_k)$ converges, it follows that $q_{n+1} =q_1 + s_n$ converges

Comment: I can't understand how you did get the $\;<\;$ inequality in your center line, and the conclusion that $\;q_n\;$ is convergent follows but *not* that immediate: some work there is still due (you can leave it that way but, perhaps, remark that still something must be done)

Comment: Nice. Now that inequality is clear...since $\;q_n\;$ is always positive. The deduction that $\;q_n\;$ is convergent can now be safely left to the OP (inductive argument). +1

Comment: The Edit is fine, yet something more must, imo, be added: there are sequences $\;a_n\;$ such that $\;|a_{n+1}-a_n|\to0\;$ yet the limit of the sequence **does not exist finitely** (i.e., the sequence isn't Cauchy). If you leave the above as it is it could mean like you're doing this...

Comment: @DonAntonio : Now, the OP has (almost) no work left :-)

Comment: Oh, he does...yet he asked for *help*, so at least to remind this. Perhaps something like  "From this we can deduce the sequence is Cauchy and..."

Answer (score 4):

We have the general term. With it, the existence and the value for the limit are proven.

For some values of $A$ and $B$ we have.

$$x_n=A(1-\sqrt{2})^n+B(1+\sqrt{2})^n$$

$$L=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{A(1-\sqrt{2})^n+B(1+\sqrt{2})^n}{A(1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}+B(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}$$

$$L=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{A(1-\sqrt{2})^n}{(1+\sqrt{2})^n}+\dfrac{B(1+\sqrt{2})^n}{(1+\sqrt{2})^n}}{\dfrac{A(1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{(1+\sqrt{2})^n}+\dfrac{B(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{(1+\sqrt{2})^n}}$$

$$L=\dfrac{0+B}{0+B(1+\sqrt{2})}=\sqrt{2}-1$$

(the $0$'s come from the exponentials with base less that $1$, as they go to zero as the exponent goes to infinity)

No mind what values for $A$ and $B$ we have, so is, the limit is that, irrespective of the values for $x_1$ and $x_2$.

**Added**
Suppose the sequence has this form $x_n=A·r^n$ and check if it is possible for $r$ and $A$ to meet the conditions the recurrence law imposes:

$A·r^{n+1}=2A·r^n+A·r^{n-1}$ or $A·r^2r^{n-1}=A2·r·r^{n-1}+Ar^{n-1}$

But obviously $A\neq0$ and $r\neq0$, so we can simplify and $r$ must satisfy:

$r^2-2r-1=0$ with roots $1-\sqrt{2}$ and $1+\sqrt{2}$

But the equation is linear, thus a linear combination of solutions is too a solution:

$x_n=A(1-\sqrt{2})^n+B(1+\sqrt{2})^n$

Comment: How do you know that $A$ and $B$ (not depending on $n$) exist?

Comment: The linear recurrence laws are always combination of exponentials with the bases the roots of the equation formed with the terms: $r^2-2r-1=0$ in this case.

Comment: @RafaBudría Kavi, you, and I know that . But it may not be obvious to the question author.

Comment: @MartinR I was thinking of that, but my son, in first course in university is said that property. I supposed it known. Anyway, I can suplement my answer.

Comment: @RafaBudría: $1-\sqrt{2}$ will not be the limit as the $x_n$'s are positive?

Comment: @YadatiKiran. We get $\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}$, but $\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}-1}{(1+\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}-1)}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2-1}=\sqrt{2}-1$

Answer (score 2):

We have $x_n$ to be monotonically increasing and since $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=2+\dfrac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}$, we can say $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<3$ as $\dfrac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}<1$ (monotoniclly increasing)$\,\:\forall\:n\geq1$. So $x_n$ is convergent.

Let $x_n=A\cdot a^n,\:a\neq0$. The recurrence relation becomes $$ A\cdot a^{n+1}=2A\cdot a^n+A\cdot a^{n-1}\implies A\cdot  a^{n-1}(a^2-2a-1)=0\underset{\substack{A\neq0\\a\neq0}}{\implies} a^2-2a-1=0$$

By quadratic formula, $a=\dfrac{2\pm\sqrt{4+4}}{2}=1\pm\sqrt{2}$. Since $x_n$'s are non negative, we have $a=\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1+\sqrt{2}$ 
$\rule{17cm}{0.5pt}$

$x_n=A(1+\sqrt{2})^n+B(1-\sqrt{2})^n$ where $A,B$ are independent of $n$ by linear recurrence.

So if $L=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{A(1+\sqrt{2})^n+B(1-\sqrt{2})^n}{A(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}+B(1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{A+\dfrac{B(1-\sqrt{2})^n}{B(1+\sqrt{2})^n}}{\dfrac{A(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{(1-\sqrt{2})^n}+\dfrac{B(1-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{B(1+\sqrt{2})^n}}=\dfrac{A}{A(1+\sqrt{2})}=\sqrt{2}-1$.

$\left(\text{Since}\: |1-\sqrt{2}|<1\implies \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\sqrt{2})^n\to0\right)$.

To show that the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$ exists  we see that it is bounded since $$0<\dfrac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}=\dfrac{x_n}{2x_{n}+x_{n-1}}\leq\dfrac{x_n}{2x_{n}}=\dfrac12 $$
and $x_{n+1}\geq2x_n\implies x_{n+1}\geq x_n$ which gives $\dfrac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}=\dfrac{2x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}}{2x_{n}+x_{n-1}}\leq\dfrac{2x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}}{2x_{n}}$ i.e.$\dfrac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}-\dfrac{x_{n-1}}{x_{n}}\leq\dfrac{x_{n-2}}{2x_{n}}$ which shows monotonicity.Hence the limit exists.

Comment: Wrong. The sequence of ratios is not monotonic. $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$, $x_3=5$, $x_4=12$, $x_5=29$ et cetera. Check for yourself that $x_3/x_2$ is larger than $x_4/x_3$ but also $x_5/x_4$ is larger than $x_4/x_3$. Those ratios jump around the limit approaching it from both sides.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I was talking of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ not the sequence of ratios. I have tried to show the limit of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ and then tried to estimate the limit of the sequence of ratios.

Comment: Ok. But $(x_n)$ being monotonic does not imply that $(x_{n-1}/x_n)$ converges. Neither does $(x_n)$, so exactly what are you trying to say in the first paragraph?

Comment: I never said that. I have assumed that the limit exists but yes I agree I have to show it does. The answer is incomplete.

Comment: Ok. I do approve of your solution of actually solving the recurrence. That does provide the rigor (if you show that $A\neq0$). Adding my upvote. IMHO your answer would be better without that first paragraph :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Sir But $A=0$ would not be inaccordance with the linear recurrence laws.

Comment: What I meant is that the recurrence relation has a solution $x_n=B(1-\sqrt2)^n$ for which we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}=\frac1{\sqrt2-1}=\sqrt2+1.$$ This **is** in accordance with the recurrence relation. But it is **not compatible** with $x_0=1, x_1=2$. Therefore we must have a sequence such that $A\neq0$.  Anyway, for the given sequence $(x_n)$ we have $A\neq0$ and your argument works. If this is what you meant, then we agree. Sorry about not making all this clear :-)

Comment: Yes that is what I meant sir.

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to use the given limit to derive the existence of it.

Write $y_n=\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}$.

> **Claim:** There exists $r\in (0,1)$ such that 
>   $$(\sqrt 2-1)-y_n\le r\big(y_{n-1}-(\sqrt2-1)\big).$$

*Proof:* Rearranging the terms,
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}}_{=1/ {y_n}}-1&=\underbrace{\frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}}_{=y_{n-1}}+1\\
\frac 1{y_n}-(\sqrt2+1)&=y_{n-1}-(\sqrt2-1)\\
\frac 1{y_n}-\frac1{\sqrt2-1}&=y_{n-1}-(\sqrt2-1)\\
(\sqrt 2-1)-y_n&=\underbrace{y_n(\sqrt2-1)}_{\in(0,1)}\big(y_{n-1}-(\sqrt2-1)\big).
\end{align*}
so the claim is true. $\square$

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
|y_n-(\sqrt2-1)|&\le r |y_{n-1}-(\sqrt2-1)|\le r^2 |y_{n-2}-(\sqrt2-1)|\le\cdots\\
&\le r^{n}|y_0-(\sqrt2-1)|\to0,
\end{align*}
implies the limit exists, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}y_n=\sqrt2-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at $x_n/x_{n+1} - x_{n-1}/x_n$ which is $(x_n^2 - x_{n-1}x_{n+1})/x_n x_{n-1}$. 
We can prove by induction that the numerator is $(-1)^n$.
$$x_{n+1}^2 - x_n x_{n+2}
= x_{n+1}^2 - x_n(2x_{n+1} + x_n)
= x_{n+1}(x_{n+1} - 2x_n) - x_n^2
= -(x_n^2 - x_{n-1}x_{n+1})$$
with $x_1^2 - x_0x_2 = -1$. Hence $x_n/x_{n+1}$ tends to a limit by the alternating series test.

Comment: You may want to use \frac{}{} to write fractions more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_n$ is increasing, all the terms become non-zero. By defining $a_n={x_n\over x_{n+1}}$ we have $${x_n\over x_{n+1}}={x_n\over 2x_n+x_{n-1}}={1\over 2+{x_{n-1}\over {x_n}}}$$therefore $$a_n={1\over 2+{ a_{n-1}}}$$Now by defining $b_n=a_n-(\sqrt 2-1)$ we have $$b_n+\sqrt 2-1={1\over b_{n-1}+\sqrt 2+1}$$therefore $$b_n=-\sqrt 2+1+{1\over b_{n-1}+\sqrt 2+1}={(1-\sqrt 2)b_{n-1}\over a_n+2}$$since $x_n>0$ we have $a_n>0$ therefore$$|b_n|=|{(1-\sqrt 2)b_{n-1}\over a_n+2}|\le {\sqrt 2-1\over 2}|b_{n-1}|$$which means that $b_n \to 0$ or $a_n={x_n\over x_{n+1}}\to \sqrt 2-1 \quad\blacksquare$

Answer (score -1):

Let

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_{n-1}}{x_{n1}} = k$$

Now

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} = k$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_n}{2x_{n} + x_{n-1}} = k$$

Take $x_n$ out from numerator and denominator
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2 + \frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}} = k$$

Using the first equation

$$ \frac{1}{2 + k} = k$$
$$k^2+2k-1=0$$
This gives two solutions $k=\sqrt{2}-1$ and $k=-\sqrt{2}-1$. Since none of the terms can be negative, we reject . the second solution thereby giving us

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} = k = \sqrt2 - 1$$

**EDIT** - As suggested by the commenter we need to prove that it is a finite limit before we start with the proof. Initially it's a $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form as both $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ approach $\infty$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$. I'll use a finite upper bound to show that the limit is finite which means it exists.

For any $n$

$$\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} =\frac{x_n}{2x_n + x_{n-1}}$$

As $x_{n-1}$ is always a positive quantity
$$\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} \leq \frac{x_n}{2x_n}$$
$$\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} \leq \frac{1}{2}$$

For any $n$, you can take the last statement to prove the monotonicity as
$$x_{n+1}\geq x_n$$
And since both $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ are positive values, the lower bound is $0$. The upper bound along with lower bound and the monotonicity proves that the limit is finite.

Comment: This seems to be the less hard part of the question. The hardest part is to **prove** the limit exists...

Comment: Is there any way to independently do that ?

Comment: Why can you write the first line? why is the limit of $\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} = \frac{x_{n-1}}{x_n}$ ?

Comment: @SauhardSharma It better is, otherwise your whole answer is invalid as you can use arithmetic of limits **only** if you *know that the limit exists finitely*, otherwise you can't. You can try induction, for example, to prove monotonicity or something like that

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I think the edited proof should suffice

Comment: Good addition yet not enough yet, as that only shows the sequence is bounded but still we need to prove the limit exists. Maybe showing the sequence is monotonic...if possible.

Comment: For any $n$, you can take the last statement to prove the monotonicity as

$$x_{n+1}\geq 2x_n$$
$$x_{n+1}\geq x_n$$

And sinc eboth $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$, therefore the lower limit is $0$, therby bounding the limit between upper and lower bounds, which along with monotonicity should prove that the limit is finite and it exists

Comment: @M-S-R we can write it as for n tending to $\infty$, if the limit exists, then at infinity they would both approach the same limit